# Not able to retrieve session value after redirection

Tags: php, session

I am setting a value of session variable on customfrom.php. On the same page if I am retrieving the value then it gives the right value and works fine.

```
session_start();
// store session data
$_SESSION['userwith'] = $_POST['hpuploaderemail'];
echo $_SESSION['userwith'];
```

But after redirection on single.php when I am trying to access session varibale this is not working. It is giving "no".

code on single.php is:

```
<?php

session_start();     

if(isset($_SESSION['userwith']))
echo $_SESSION['userwith'];
else
echo "no";
?>
```

Comment: Is the session properly initialized in both scripts ? Are you using the same session name ?

Comment: how do you redirect to single.php?

Comment: By a form submission. and have coded on function.php {if(isset($_POST['publishpost'])){ session_start();
// store session data
$_SESSION['userwith']=$_POST['hphuploaderemail'];
}}

Comment: @Burak you have solved my problem.. Sorry I found the the solution of my problem.. I was doing a mistake on redirection . I have used this one {session_destroy();}. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may a case when you have destroyed the session.
Please check if your code doesn't contains `session_destroy();`

Comment: yes thats was the problem. and @Burak has already indicated me about this.

Comment: Oh! i didn't noticed the comments (I had once the same problem when I was a beginner so I thought it may help).